# Get type literal of tuple value in array of tuples

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples

Given array

```js
const arr = [[0, 'foo'], [1, 'bar']] as const;
```

I need value to be concrete literal value, not `string` or `'foo' | 'bar'`.

```js
const value = get(arr, 0); // value type: 'foo'
```

My best try was

```js
type Entry<K, V> = readonly [K, V];
type GetType<A extends readonly Entry<any, any>[], K> = A extends readonly Entry<K, infer V>[] ? V : never;

function get<K extends PropertyKey, V extends string>(arr: readonly Entry<K, V>[], id: K): GetType<typeof arr, K> {
  return new Map(arr).get(id)!;
}

const arr = [[0, 'foo'], [1, 'bar']] as const;
const val = get(arr, 0);
```

But it results in val type being `'foo' | 'bar'`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXzEom) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend writing `get()` so that the relationship between the  [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters and the function parameters are as straightforward as necessary to get the proper inference.  So instead of having `arr` be of a type related to two separate type parameters, I'd suggest make `arr` be of a type related to just one type parameter in a simple way, and have `id` be related to the other one.

For example:

```
function get<T extends readonly [PropertyKey, string], K extends T[0]>(
    arr: readonly T[], id: K
): Extract<T, readonly [K, any]>[1] {
    return new Map(arr).get(id)!;
}
```

Here the type of `arr` is a (possibly `readonly`) array of elements of type `T`, which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a (possibly `readonly`) entry tuple type.  So if you pass in `get([[k1, v1], [k2, v2], [k3, v3]], ...)` then `T` should be inferred as the equivalent of [the union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `[typeof k1, typeof v1] | [typeof k2, typeof v2] | [typeof k3, typeof v3]`.  And the type of `id` is `K` which is constrained to be one of the keys in the `T` union of tuple types (which you get by [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T` with an index of `0`).

To determine the return type, we need to take the union `T` and [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) the union member whose key corresponds to `K`.  Once we do that we get the value type from that entry, by indexing into it with an index of `1`.

Let's test it out:

```
const val = get(arr, 0);
// const val: "foo"
const val2 = get(arr, 1);
// const val2: "bar"
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2ugDAGhgcgDMQR8BdPdARj3wCNFyz4IZRIoBuAWACg-CAVzDAoAS3AwA5gFMoAHgAqMGQA8oMsABNWCGXC3gANgE8MABQQgADjIRQTAaRkm80BGLBSKMRyvWaOjCK2GQAfAAUfACQiAgAXDB6BsZmIT5iWomOfACUiQCi6ghwokp4yYZgphiOeHBgJuHUzADeMXpQgghgMGAyAO4wALJw1hFxuQB0slARmbkAhDy8AL58fOzQMABucEao0nITSHhYuSsA9Jds4Nt7RokARMQgT5t3sA8ATIezJwg8FQLnxrrcOLt9t9ngwEO9eEA)